Increase Dash icon size
I installed Ubuntu 23.10 on my Pi5 and am still setting it up.
I wanted to use Mac like settings (with Close button on left) and installed Tweaks, which worked.
Either this (or something else I did) resulted in my Dash having small icons.
How can I change the Dash icon size? Everything else seems to be OK

You may want to read What's the difference between dash and dock?
How to change the dock icon size

Click on the top right icons at the top bar.
Click on the "Gear" icon to open the Settings Window.

Click on the Ubuntu Desktop on the left panel.
Change the icon size by sliding the slider.


Note, in Ubuntu Dash has been turned into Dock. You may see more about the features and configurability of the Dock here.
Hope this helps
